# How to properly route to JSON entry in Express

Tags: javascript, json, express

I am building a simple Express-based API to serve up a JSON data file. It's working fine but I'd like to add functionality. The JSON file is of the following format: (portions omitted)

```
[{
  "ID": "1",
  "NAME": "George Washington",
  "PAGE": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Washington",
  "DATE1": "30/04/1789",
  "DATE2": "4/03/1797",
  "PARTY": "Independent ",
  "IMG": "GeorgeWashington.jpg",
  "THUMB": "thmb_GeorgeWashington.jpg",
  "HOMESTATE": "Virginia"
}
```

And here's a snippet from my **index.js** for Express routing:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var myData = require('./data.json');

app.get('/api', function(req, res){
res.json(myData);
});

app.get('/api/:id', function(req, res){
  res.json(myData[req.params.id]);
  });
```

A call to **/api** gives to the whole dataset, while a call to **/api/1** gives just the first entry, as I hoped. What I would like to do is add a third (or more route) that allows the user to drill down to specific items in the JSON. For example a call to

```
https//<blah>/api/1/HOMESTATE
```

would yield

```
"HOMESTATE": "Virginia"
```

Can I do this using parameters, or do I need to iterate over the JSON based on the entered ID? Any pointers to code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can easily be accomplished with just route parameters.

```
app.get('/api/:id/:property', function(req, res){
  var response = {};
  response[req.params.property] = myData[req.params.id][req.params.property]
  res.json(response);
});
```

You are going to want to add some error handling to make things more robust, otherwise your app will crash if the route parameters aren't valid.

Comment: That worked like a champ. Only hiccup is the routes are case sensitive using OpenShift, but that's for another day. Thanks @Emzy